# Best way to validate 2 fields with standard form using symfony 2.7

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I've a standard form (without object) and I need to check if field1 < field2. If not I would like to display the error in the form like I do when I'm using form validation with object.

I red http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validating-values-and-arrays but it's for assert constraints. Mine is specific.

I also red this http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#adding-validation. But once again, it use constraint validation.

Maybe I need to use this : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html.

Thanks for your advices

Comment: so you read a bit, that's great. But did you actually *try* what you assume might help?

Comment: I didn't try last point but I thought that it was not a good solution. Create it's own assert only for one verification... I thought that I was in the rong way.

Comment: is there a reason you are unwilling to create the class and use custom [getters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#getters)?

Comment: It's because the form is simply a search filter.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, here is my solution.

In my controller, If my condition is true, than I'm using the code to set an error and return the form. That's way, I see my error for the specific field.

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormError;

...

$form = $this->createForm(new formType());

$form->get('my-field')->addError(new FormError($this->get('translator')->trans('error.message.greather.than')));

return $this->render('MyBundle:Default:search.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
```

I'm not sure that it's the best way but it works for me.